# reading input from stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm reading input to a char array of size 5,

```
stringstream ss;

char a[5];

if (!ss.read(a, 5))
{
    // throw exception
}

if (!ss.get(a, 5))
{
   // throw exception
}
```

Both of these functions seem to work, is there any difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ss.read`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/) will read 5 bytes from the stream, unless it hits the end of the stream.

[`ss.get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/)  will read 4 bytes, unless it hits the delimiter ('\n') or end of the stream.  It will also null-terminate the string.

Answer (score 3):

The former will read 5 bytes, stopping early only upon encountering EOF.

The latter will read *4* bytes (allowing room for null-termination), stopping early upon encountering EOF *or* upon encountering `'\n'`.

Which one you want depends on whether or not you intend for `a` to behave semantically as a C-string.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/

Read is when you need blocks of data ( Ex: ss.read( a, 2 ) ) - This does not store it as a c-string and not null terminated.

Get - Extracts characters from the stream and stores them as a c-string into the array beginning at ss. Execution stops if there are delimiting characters like '\n' too.

Answer (score 1):

ss.get gives you unformatyed data, ss.read gives you a block, both inherited from istream [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)